# how to import an animated fbx/obj file into my WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, fbx

I'm trying to import an animated obj or fbx file to my WPF project.

ps: I already managed to import a static obj file but I need it with animation.

Comment: HelixToolkit has support OBJ format.

Comment: I know, I already imported an obj file with HelixToolkit  but I need it with its animation

Comment: Hi @Yasmine got any solutions?

Comment: Sorry, I stopped working on that project.